# Session variable storing the value on localhost but not after the publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

While debugging the code it runs without any problem. But when I publish on the Intranet, it does not run how I want.

This is login code, in here there is no problem. It redirects to Default page:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            User _user = new User();
            _user = _user.SignIn(userName, password);

            if (_user == null)
                throw new Exception("Username or password is wrong.");
            else
            {
                Session.Add("User", _user);

                if (Request["_RDR"] != null)
                    Response.Redirect(Request["_RDR"].ToString());
                else
                    Response.Redirect("~/");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblErrorText.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

This is SignIn method in User class, there is also no problem in here. It still runs perfectly:

```
public User SignIn(string _username, string _password)
    {
        User _user = new User();
        
        Erm_TransferOrderServiceClient client = new Erm_TransferOrderServiceClient();
        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = _username;
        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = _password;

        CallContext context = new CallContext();
        context.Company = "ERH";

        try
        {
            _user.UserName = _username;
            _user.Password = _password;

            string personnelNumber = client.getPersonnelNumber(context); //just trying to connect the server
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return _user;
    }
```

This is default page load. The problem is in here, it redirects to login page again. I think ActiveUser method returns null:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        User _user = User.ActiveUser();
        if (_user == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            RefreshGridData();
        }
    }
```

Here is ActiveUser method in User class:

```
public static User ActiveUser()
    {
        try
        {
            var tempUser = HttpContext.Current.Session["User"] as User;

            User _user = new User();
            _user = _user.SignIn(tempUser.UserName, tempUser.Password);

            return _user;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I tried a sample to understand the problem. In Login page Session is created and the values are correct. But when I redirect it to Default page it became null and because of that it redirects to login page directly.

EDIT2: I tried to login several times and login is successfull around 20% and it redirects to Default page. After around 15-20 seconds the session value turns null and it redirects to login page again.

Comment: Your ActiveUser method may return NULL because your _user.SignIn is returning NULL when is catching exceptions. I think this is the main problem and not the session.

Comment: @DA In ActiveUser method i tried returning tempUser without using SignIn method but still it returns null. I don't think its about SignIn method. It doesn't return null on button click method also.

Comment: also, keep in mind that any un-handled errors will in most cases blow up and out the session state. As a result, unless you have REALLY fantastic error free code? I high recommend that you adopt SQL server session states, and that tends to fix 99% of such issues and problems, since a un-handled error (which tends to trigger a app pool restart), or even a app pool re-start will not destroy session.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal thank you for the information. But in SignIn method it can only end up in catch when the server connection fails or the username or password is wrong. And this scenario I can see that session is not null in login screen its becoming null after the redirect.

Comment: Using some cloud hosting (such as Azure or amazon), then those are fail safe servers, and thus you have at least 3 servers running your code. If between a ping, and another server is used, then "in memory" session will not work, since each of the fail safe multiple servers can't share their memory, and hence using SQL based sessions is a requirement.  So, when using a load balancing farm, or a server farm, then in theory with servers are running a copy of your web site, then you have no choice in that from one page to the next page which server is used and thus need SQL server based sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried most of the solution I can find in the internet and here is how I solve my problem.

Firstly the default session state mode is **InProc** and as much as I can understand it's not reliable. I turned that to **StateServer**.

```
<system.web>
 <sessionState mode="StateServer"
   stateConnectionString="tcpip=serverip:42424"
   cookieless="false"
   timeout="600"/>
<system.web/>
```

After I turned my sessionState mode to StateServer, I activated the **ASP.NET State Service** on the server. You can find it on the **services.msc**.

Still it's not fixed you have 2 step to go. If you are using StateServer mode for sessionState, your object(which session holds) needs to be **Serializable**. My session holds User object so I made the User class serializable.

```
[Serializable]
public class User
{
    //variables, methods etc.
}
```

And lastly **AllowRemoteConnection** value needs to be "1". Open your **regedit** and find it in here. *\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters*